# Airflow, Connecting to MsSql error "Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist"

Tags: airflow

I'm getting this error when trying to use Airflow to get_records().

**pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (localhost:None)\n')**

I used this guide on how to setup.
https://tech.marksblogg.com/mssql-sql-server-linux-install-tutorial-and-guide.html

Using Python REPL, I can connect and return a result.

```
with pymssql.connect(server="localhost",
                 user="SA",
                 password="password",
                 database="database_name") as conn:
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM currency", conn)
print(df)

with pymssql.connect(server="127.0.0.1",
                 user="SA",
                 password="password",
                 database="database_name") as conn:
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM currency", conn)
print(df)
```

I update my Airflow Connections with either of these setups and the run a test.

```
 airflow test run_test_db test_database 2015-06-01
```

The error is produced....

Any ideas please? The whole setup is contained within the one linux (vagrant) machine, no virtual environments.... So its using the same version of pymssql to try an connect....

**EDIT UPDATE**

Whats really annoying is if i use the same connection string in a DAG there is no error and it runs perfectly fine...

So the connection string that is retrieved from the database must change.

Is there a way to debug/print the string/connection properties?

Example working DAG

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks.mssql_hook import MsSqlHook
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pymssql 
import pandas as pd

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 2, 13),
    'email': ['example@email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('run_test_db', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="0 01 * * 2-6")


def test_db(**context):
    with pymssql.connect(server="localhost",
                    user="SA",
                    password="Password123",
                    database="database") as conn:
                    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM champ_dw_dim_currency", conn)
                    print(df)

test_database = PythonOperator(
    task_id='test_database',
    python_callable=test_db,
    execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=3),
    dag=dag,
    provide_context=True,
    op_kwargs={
        'extra_detail': 'nothing'
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure your'e using the correct **port**? (apparently `MsSQL-Server`'s *default port* is 1433)

Comment: @y2k-shubham including 1433 in the connection string did solve the issue.... interesting.... i thought reading the pymssql docs 1433 was default included if not present

Comment: @y2k-shubham I am using MWAA Airflow 2 , It failed for connection, I have used connection URI String as `mssql://UserName:pwd@host.us-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com:1433` . Could you please guide me

Comment: did you find an answer? this is also happening to me while the code used to work well